# JMESPath descend in tree for filter

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, jmespath

## What I'm trying to achieve

I want to extract the volume ID for the root block device using `describe-instances`.

## What I tried so far

`` aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=tag:Backup,Values=True" --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].{Name: Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value | [0], Id: InstanceId, Block: BlockDeviceMappings[?DeviceName==RootDeviceName].Ebs.VolumeId, Test: RootDeviceName}' ``

## What's not working

Several things:

1. `Ebs.VolumeId` is not the direct descendant of `DeviceName`, it is descending from `BlockDeviceMappings`.
2. `RootDeviceName` is not a descendant of `BlockDeviceMappings`.

So when I'm trying to pull the `RootDeviceName` and search the `VolumeId` accordingly I'm getting a blank field (Block: is for testing and irrelevant to the case).

The first 2 fields are correct.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is quite an ask!

The closest I got working was to specify the actual value for `DeviceName`:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].[InstanceId, BlockDeviceMappings[?DeviceName==`/dev/xvda`].Ebs.VolumeId]'
```

(This syntax worked on a Mac.)

Frankly, I'd recommend using a language to make the call (eg Python) and then apply your own logic, rather than trying to convince JMESPath to extract the correct values.

It would be something like this:

```
import boto3

ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2', region_name = 'ap-southeast-2')

response = ec2_client.describe_instances(
    Filters=[
        {
            'Name': 'tag:Backup',
            'Values': ['True']
        }
    ]
)

for r in response['Reservations']:
    for i in r['Instances']:
        name = [t['Value'] for t in i['Tags'] if t['Key'] == 'Name'][0]
        for b in i['BlockDeviceMappings']:
            if b['DeviceName'] == i['RootDeviceName']:
                print (i['InstanceId'], name, b['Ebs']['VolumeId'])
```

Comment: I honestly don't know what to say because it's supposed to be dynamic and I also managed to use dynamic variables the way I figured they should be used, do you think I should report a bug?

Comment: Do as you wish, but the question is whether the problem lies in JMESPath or in the AWS CLI implementation of it. I've added some Python code that should do the job for you.

Comment: According to `pip freeze` my `jmespath` version is the latest (0.9.3).