# Issue with AWS CLI commands / JMESPATH query

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, jmespath

Can anyone of you please help me in identifying the issue with the CLI commands /JMESPATH queries in the Section  - "What's Not Working? below

P.S. JSON output given below is valid and you can use the output to test the JMESPATH query part of it out on JMESPATH.org

### What Works?

1) `aws ec2 describe-security-groups --query SecurityGroups[?GroupId=='sg-0a26abc0a00000000'].IpPermissions[]`
2) `aws ec2 describe-security-groups --query SecurityGroups[?GroupId=='sg-0a26abc0a00000000'].IpPermissions[].FromPort`
3) `aws ec2 describe-security-groups --query SecurityGroups[?GroupId=='sg-0a26abc0a00000000'].IpPermissions[].IpProtocol`

### What's Not Working?

1) `aws ec2 describe-security-groups --query SecurityGroups[?GroupId=='sg-0a26abc0a00000000'].IpPermissions[?IpProtocol=='tcp'].IpProtocol`
2) `aws ec2 describe-security-groups --query SecurityGroups[?GroupId=='sg-0a26abc0a00000000'].IpPermissions[?FromPort=='22'].FromPort`

### JSON OUTPUT

```
{
    "SecurityGroups": [
        {
            "Description": "default VPC security group",
            "GroupName": "default",
            "IpPermissions": [
                {
                    "IpProtocol": "-1",
                    "IpRanges": [],
                    "Ipv6Ranges": [],
                    "PrefixListIds": [],
                    "UserIdGroupPairs": [
                        {
                            "GroupId": "sg-06d7c8d3300000000",
                            "UserId": "400000000000"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "OwnerId": "400000000000",
            "GroupId": "sg-06d7c000000000000",
            "IpPermissionsEgress": [
                {
                    "IpProtocol": "-1",
                    "IpRanges": [
                        {
                            "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                        }
                    ],
                    "Ipv6Ranges": [],
                    "PrefixListIds": [],
                    "UserIdGroupPairs": []
                }
            ],
            "VpcId": "vpc-0d26c7ba200000000"
        },
        {
            "Description": "BastionSG",
            "GroupName": "BastionSG",
            "IpPermissions": [
                {
                    "FromPort": 22,
                    "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                    "IpRanges": [
                        {
                            "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                        }
                    ],
                    "Ipv6Ranges": [],
                    "PrefixListIds": [],
                    "ToPort": 22,
                    "UserIdGroupPairs": []
                }
            ],
            "OwnerId": "400000000000",
            "GroupId": "sg-0a26abc0a00000000",
            "IpPermissionsEgress": [
                {
                    "IpProtocol": "-1",
 "IpRanges": [
                        {
                            "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                        }
                    ],
                    "Ipv6Ranges": [],
                    "PrefixListIds": [],
                    "UserIdGroupPairs": []
                }
            ],
            "VpcId": "vpc-0d26c7ba200000000"
        }
    ]
}
```

### Expected/Actual Results

`aws ec2 describe-security-groups --query SecurityGroups[?GroupId=='sg-0a26abc0a00000000'].IpPermissions[?IpProtocol=='tcp'].IpProtocol`

### Result

Expected - tcp, Actual - Returns no result

`aws ec2 describe-security-groups --query SecurityGroups[?GroupId=='sg-0a26abc0a00000000'].IpPermissions[?FromPort=='22'].FromPort`

### Result

Expected - 22, Actual - Returns no result

Comment: I tried with the online JMESPATH evaluator at http://jmespath.org/ and it does not seem to support filters within filtered results. The ABNF grammar describes list-filter-expr but then fails to reference that from anywhere else in the grammar (which is presumably an error in the documentation). My guess is that JMESPATH simply does not support this usage, You could take it up with them at https://gitter.im/jmespath/chat.

Comment: It sort of worked on my Mac with `aws ec2 describe-security-groups --query 'SecurityGroups[].IpPermissions[?FromPort==\`22\`].FromPort'`, but gave empty sets too.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, Did we just find a bug in AWS CLI?

Comment: Frankly, I find it easier to query such information via the SDK, rather than attempting to force JMESPath to produce a particular result. For example: [JMESPath descend in tree for filter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53943306/174777)

Comment: I spent some time on this too and I also think JMESPath is broken.

Comment: @AlexHarvey I don't think its broken. check my answer. It's just issue with using singlequotes and backquotes at proper locations. Let me know. @John since `IpPermissions` is an array you need to pipe the filtered array and extract `FromPort` in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the ones I tried and got expected data back. Let me know if this works for you.

```
aws ec2 describe-security-groups --query 'SecurityGroups[?GroupId==`sg-xxxxxx`].[IpPermissions[?IpProtocol==`tcp`] | [0].IpProtocol]' --output text
//tcp
aws ec2 describe-security-groups --query 'SecurityGroups[?GroupId==`sg-xxxxxx`].[IpPermissions[?FromPort==`22`] | [0].FromPort]' --output text
//22
```

Note  -

1. It is better surround your query within single quotes so CLI can properly parse the entire query.
2. You can fill conditions with backquote(`).

Comment: I could be misunderstanding but this seems like a workaround to JMESPath being broken and I still can't understand why it is necessary to coerce to an array and then take the first element of that array again.

Comment: @AlexHarvey I absolutely agree. Having expression like `IpPermissions[?IpProtocol==`tcp`].IpProtocol` makes it very simple and I being getting used `jq` expressions want to try this way only. By the way in above expression `[0]` is not necessary and you can give `[].IpProtocol` since array already filtered down to single row.

Comment: I do see a problem with JMESPATH and that is to do with the quotes and their usage. It works only if you put or use them in a certain way. Please find below a few tests i have done with different combinations of quotes. This is also confusing at times when you are not sure which one's to use. I am not sure if there is any documentation out there for the usage of quotes. Please find my tests in the comments below.

Comment: Test1 -> NoOutsideQuotes/DoubleQuotes
-------------------------------------
aws ec2 describe-security-groups --query SecurityGroups[?GroupId=="sg-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"].IpPermissions[]
Result:
Bad value for --query SecurityGroups[?GroupId==sg-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx].IpPermissions[]: Expecting: rbracket, got: number: Parse error at column 27, token "0" (NUMBER), for expression:
"SecurityGroups[?GroupId==sg-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx].IpPermissions[]"

Comment: Test2 -> NoOutSideQuotes/SingleQuotes->
aws ec2 describe-security-groups --query SecurityGroups[?GroupId=='sg-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'].IpPermissions[]
Result->
Bad value for --query SecurityGroups[?GroupId==sg-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx].IpPermissions[]: Expecting: rbracket, got: number: Parse error at column 27, token "0" (NUMBER), for expression:
"SecurityGroups[?GroupId==sg-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx].IpPermissions[]"

Comment: Test3 -> OutSideDoubleQuotes/SingleQuotes->
aws ec2 describe-security-groups --query "SecurityGroups[?GroupId=='sg-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'].IpPermissions[]"
Result->
[
    {
        "FromPort": 22,
        "IpProtocol": "tcp",
        "IpRanges": [
            {
                "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
            }
        ],
        "Ipv6Ranges": [],
        "PrefixListIds": [],
        "ToPort": 22,
        "UserIdGroupPairs": []
    }
]

Comment: Test4 -> OutSideSingleQuotes/DoubleQuotes ->
aws ec2 describe-security-groups --query 'SecurityGroups[?GroupId=="sg-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"].IpPermissions[]'
Result->
[]

Comment: Test5 -> OutSideDoubleQuotes/BackQuotes->
aws ec2 describe-security-groups --query "SecurityGroups[?GroupId==`sg-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`].IpPermissions[]"

Result->
bash: sg-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx: command not found

Bad value for --query SecurityGroups[?GroupId==].IpPermissions[]: invalid token: Parse error at column 25, token "]" (RBRACKET), for expression:
"SecurityGroups[?GroupId==].IpPermissions[]"

Comment: Test6 -> OutSideSingleQuotes/BackQuotes ->
aws ec2 describe-security-groups --query 'SecurityGroups[?GroupId==`sg-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`].IpPermissions[]'
Result->
[
    {
        "FromPort": 22,
        "IpProtocol": "tcp",
        "IpRanges": [
            {
                "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
            }
        ],
        "Ipv6Ranges": [],
        "PrefixListIds": [],
        "ToPort": 22,
        "UserIdGroupPairs": []
    }
]

Comment: @ykm I understand you are new to stackoverflow but let's go one problem at a time. what is the error you are getting when you try with the way I shown in answer?. 1. Keep query within single quotes. 2. conditions in backquotes. I think you tried under Test6. Is Test6 result is not what you are looking for?

Comment: @Imran, Thank you, I have tested both your queries. They are working fine, and i am getting the expected answer. BTW, what makes you think i am new to stackoverflow :) ? or Does it really matter?

Comment: @ykm I got bunch of notifications one by one :) you could wait for my response and let us resolve one issue at a time :)

Comment: @ykm if you are ok with my response then you can accept the answer :) I found below few proposals on literals used in jmespath if its any helpful for you. http://jmespath.org/proposals/filter-expressions.html . http://jmespath.org/proposals/raw-string-literals.html

Comment: @imran, the reason was, i couldn't fit all my test results into one comment. I will accept your answer and thanks again.

Comment: @ykm I think you're confused about bash's quote syntax vs jmespath's.

Comment: jmespath (as documented on jmespath.org). For this, you need to know that single quotes = json string, back quotes = everything inside is a raw json expression. Bash's quotes... eh, nightmare.

That @Imran 's use of backquotes for a string works here is a bug in the Python jmespath implementation, I believe. It does not work for Go.

Comment: (in particular, I believe point (2) is incorrect - single quotes are supposed to be an easy way to generate a JSON string literal, and are not always 'used for conditions'. For 22, we want a JSON number, so we can't use single quotes).

Answer (score 1):

```
SecurityGroups[?GroupId=='sg-0a26abc0a00000000'].IpPermissions[] | [?IpProtocol=='tcp'].IpProtocol | [0]

SecurityGroups[?GroupId=='sg-0a26abc0a00000000'].IpPermissions[] | [?FromPort==`22`].FromPort | [0]
```

Or, quoted/adjusted for bash:

```
'SecurityGroups[?GroupId==`"sg-0a26abc0a00000000"`].IpPermissions[] | [?IpProtocol==`"tcp"`].IpProtocol | [0]'

'SecurityGroups[?GroupId==`"sg-0a26abc0a00000000`"].IpPermissions[] | [?FromPort==`22`].FromPort | [0]'
```

You'll notice the `[]` at the end of IpPermissions, which flattens the list. If you don't do this (or do `SecurityGroups[?GroupId=='sg-0a26abc0a00000000'][]`), the filter is applying to the top-level of the list, where IpPermissions doesn't exist.

Why this is true is not clear to me. It does seem wrong, because without the earlier filter the later filter applies to the sublist.

Comment: please find the test results below after using your modified jmespath query

Comment: $ aws ec2 describe-security-groups --query SecurityGroups[?GroupId=="'sg-0a26abc0a00000000'"].IpPermissions[] | [?IpProtocol=='tcp'].IpProtocol | [0]

Comment: bash: [?IpProtocol==tcp].IpProtocol: command not found
bash: 0: command not found
Exception ignored in: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='cp1252'>
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument

Comment: You need to quote the query appropriately so bash doesn't interpret the pipe. In this case, I'd suggest using double quotes around the whole thing will be the easiest.

Comment: Double Quotes trick worked for text - IpProtocol='tcp' but not for number FromPort=22. Please find the results below

Comment: Result for Without Quotes - aws ec2 describe-security-groups --query "SecurityGroups[?GroupId=='sg-0a26abc0a00000000'].IpPermissions[] | [?FromPort==22].FromPort | [0]"
 Bad value for --query SecurityGroups[?GroupId=='sg-0a26abc0a00000000'].IpPermissions[] | [?FromPort==22].FromPort | [0]: invalid token: Parse error at column 79, token "22" (NUMBER), for expression:
 "SecurityGroups[?GroupId=='sg-0a26abc0a00000000'].IpPermissions[] | [?FromPort==22].FromPort | [0]"

Comment: Result for single quote - aws ec2 describe-security-groups --query "SecurityGroups[?GroupId=='sg-0a26abc0a00000000'].IpPermissions[] | [?FromPort=='22'].FromPort | [0]"
 null

Comment: Result for double quotes - aws ec2 describe-security-groups --query "SecurityGroups[?GroupId=='sg-0a26abc0a00000000'].IpPermissions[] | [?FromPort=="22"].FromPort | [0]"
 Bad value for --query SecurityGroups[?GroupId=='sg-0a26abc0a00000000'].IpPermissions[] | [?FromPort==22].FromPort | [0]: invalid token: Parse error at column 79, token "22" (NUMBER), for expression:
 "SecurityGroups[?GroupId=='sg-0a26abc0a00000000'].IpPermissions[] | [?FromPort==22].FromPort | [0]"

Comment: aws ec2 describe-security-groups --query "SecurityGroups[?GroupId=='sg-0a26abc0a00000000'].IpPermissions[] | [?FromPort==`22`].FromPort | [0]"
 bash: 22: command not found
 Bad value for --query SecurityGroups[?GroupId=='sg-0a26abc0a00000000'].IpPermissions[] | [?FromPort==].FromPort | [0]: invalid token: Parse error at column 79, token "]" (RBRACKET), for expression:
 "SecurityGroups[?GroupId=='sg-0a26abc0a00000000'].IpPermissions[] | [?FromPort==].FromPort | [0]"

Comment: Unfortunately, none of those have the right contents. Simplest is probably:

```'SecurityGroups[?GroupId==`"sg-0a26abc0a00000000"`].IpPermissions[] | [?FromPort==`22`].FromPort | [0]'```

(sorry - I forgot about the special meaning of backquotes - I don't use a Bourne shell ;) )

Comment: Strange this is it's only failing for number.

Comment: Do you use aws cli?

Comment: Frequently.

Did you try the last expression? You're either failing to copy the original expression OR quoting it incorrectly for bash. The last one I gave should be right for bash. The 'number' failing is as expected: you've trying to either compare it to a string (jmespath single quote), execute it (bash backquotes), interpret it as a jmespath number rather than a json number (no quotes). You need to use ONLY backquotes and avoid bash interpreting them, as shown in my final comment.